# NbOAuth2AuthStrategy with Keycloak returning CORS error when dockerized

Tags: angular, docker, cors, keycloak, nebular

I have dockerized an Angular webapp that is logging in to Keycloak using Nebular NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.
The application was working correctly when running on my local machine and connecting to Keycloak via an Angular Proxy.

I have now dockerized the webapp, and it is running in the same `docker-compose` as Keycloak. I would like to connect directly to keycloak within the `docker-compose` network without using any Angular proxy but it is not working. I should be able to connect from the browser at `http://localhost:4200` (container is running in the docker network at `http://web:4200`) to Keyclock (`http://keycloak:8080` in the docker network)

The error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://keycloak:8080/realms/vc/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**I have already added `http://localhost:4200` in Web Origins** in Keycloak but I still get the same error.
I am connecting directly with `NbOAuth2AuthStrategy` so I am not being redirected to any login page in Keycloak. I am using my own login page and Nebular is doing the required API calls for me.

```js
...NbAuthModule.forRoot({
  strategies: [
      NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
        name: 'keycloak',
        baseEndpoint: environment.keycloak.uri,
        clientId: environment.keycloak.client_id,
        clientSecret: environment.keycloak.client_secret,
        clientAuthMethod: NbOAuth2ClientAuthMethod.BASIC,
        authorize: {
          endpoint: '/auth',
          responseType: NbOAuth2ResponseType.TOKEN,
        },
        token: {
          endpoint: '/token',
          grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.PASSWORD,
          class: NbAuthOAuth2JWTToken,
        },
        refresh: {
          endpoint: '/token',
          grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN,
        },
      }),
    //...
```

```js
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  hasura: {
    uri: 'http://hasura:8080/v1/graphql',
    subscription_uri: 'ws://hasura:8080/v1/graphql',
    claims_namespace: "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims",
  },
  keycloak: {
    uri: "http://keycloak:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect",
    client_id: "hasura",
    client_secret: "mysecret",
  }
};
```